# I'm not getting guard flag. Whats the requirements for that?

Tags: configuration, relays, help, guard

Also, im not getting the stable flag.

I'v been online for about a month.
20.april I switched from win to linux.
I've had some restarts of the relay, but not long downtimes.

my fingerprint:
2AEB4E9200617CAE465AC789789675CBF336CAE2

does anyone have time to look into this? Thanks. :)

Comment: According to someone in #tor IRC channel, relays with dynamic IP won't get 'guard' or 'stable' Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 3):

Consider that your relay is new, since its uptime is about 2 days.

> Directory authorities assign the Guard flag to relays based on three
>   characteristics: "bandwidth" (they need to have a large enough consensus 
>   weight), "weighted fractional uptime" (they need to be working most of the > time), and "time known" (to make attacks more expensive, we don't want to > give the Guard flag to relays that haven't been around a while first). 
>   This last characteristic is most relevant here: on today's Tor network, 
>   you're first eligible for the Guard flag on day eight.

For more information please see [this article](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay).